# Can one moderator cancel or reduce the suspension given out by another?

Tags: discussion, moderation, suspensions

I was wondering if this is even discussed anywhere in the policies of this network?

Comment: This belongs on [meta.se], IMO.

Comment: I would note that even though it's always one moderator who actually applies the suspension, the decision to impose a suspension usually reflects a consensus by the entire mod team. (Same goes for the decision to cancel or reduce one.) So anyone who might be thinking of getting their suspension reversed by appealing to another moderator, it's not going to be that easy. ;-)

Comment: @DavidZ So there are not mother-mods and father-mods? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has already been answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160246/how-can-a-temporary-account-suspension-be-lifted/160250#160250). Yes, it can be done, as explained in the post I just linked. Of course, such a measure must be possible since the moderators themselves are not infallible. One cannot run the risk of a "rogue mod" ruining an entire site, or something like that.

Comment: But who moderates the moderator moderators?

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy The shareholders of the SE Inc. In their view, they focus mainly to the economical results of the company.